# Trying to write a siamese network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras, siamese-network

I would like to have 2 or more identical networks output into another network

```
def getSimpleAdditionModel():
    seq_conv_model = [
        layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=[2]),
        layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ]
    seq_model = tf.keras.Sequential(seq_conv_model)
    return seq_model


def outputModel(output1, output2):
    deq = [
        layers.Dense(32,activation='relu')(Concatenate([output1, output2])),
        layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ]
    seq_model = tf.keras.Sequential(deq)
    return seq_model


input1 = layers.Input(shape=(2,))
input2 = layers.Input(shape=(2,))

seqmodel = getSimpleAdditionModel()
output_x1 = seqmodel(input1)
output_x2 = seqmodel(input2)


model = models.Model([input1, input2], outputModel(output_x1, output_x2))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

But when I am trying to put output_x1 and output_x2 as input to the other network I am getting some errors inside outputModel. I tried without Concatenate but without success.

I wanted to achieve something similar to the article :
https://medium.com/predict/face-recognition-from-scratch-using-siamese-networks-and-tensorflow-df03e32f8cd0
without using conv neural networks

For some of the errors for the above code I get :

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("dense_6/Identity:0", shape=(None, 32), dtype=float32)
Stack is :
  File "SiameseAddition.py", line 53, in <module>
    model = models.Model([input1, input2], outputModel(output_x1, output_x2))
  File "SiameseAddition.py", line 40, in outputModel
    seq_model = tf.keras.Sequential(deq)
```

if in outputModel method I do the following instead :

```
def outputModel(output1, output2):
    deq = [
        layers.Dense(32,activation='relu')(output1, output2),
TypeError: call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
File "SiameseAddition.py", line 40, in <module>
    model = models.Model([input1, input2], outputModel(output_x1, output_x2))
```

The full code can be seen at :
https://trinket.io/python/ceafe7a256

Comment: *I am getting some errors* is not a problem description unless you tell us what those *errors* are specifically. We can't see your screen or read your mind from here. Please [edit] your question and add the exact error messages you're seeing; they're on the screen right in front of you, so there's no reason for you to not include them here so we have that information.

Comment: Sorry let me edit

Answer (score 2):

I think I found exactly what I needed on how to build a siamese network at https://github.com/aspamers/siamese/blob/master/siamese.py
The way I was creating the model was completely wrong it looks like. Like the above I am using the functional APIs and it went much smoother.
Methods became :

```
def getSimpleAdditionModel(input_shape):
    model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    layer = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(model_input)
    layer = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(layer)
    layer = layers.Dense(1)(layer)
    return tf.keras.Model(model_input, layer)



def outputModel(embedding_shape):
    embedding_a = Input(shape=embedding_shape)
    embedding_b = Input(shape=embedding_shape)

    layer = layers.Concatenate()([embedding_a, embedding_b])
    layer = layers.Dense(32,activation='relu')(layer)
    layer = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(layer)
    layer = layers.Dense(1)(layer)

    return tf.keras.Model([embedding_a, embedding_b], layer)

input1 = [2]
input2 = [2]
input_a = Input(shape=input1)
input_b = Input(shape=input2)


base_model = getSimpleAdditionModel(input1)
processed_a = base_model(input_a)
processed_b = base_model(input_b)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

oModel = outputModel(base_model.output_shape)
head = oModel([processed_a, processed_b])

model = tf.keras.Model([input_a, input_b], head)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
```

I think reusing the above link looks much better than coding the network yourself